# NullPointerException al llamar a la instancia del Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

Estoy haciendo este programa que utiliza el patron singleton para simular un login de una persona, sin embargo al llamar a la instancia del singleton me regresa null por lo tanto no puedo acceder a esos metodos que quiero imprimir

```
 package Data;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Singleton {
private static Singleton log ;
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

Singleton() {
    
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if(log!=null) {
        log = new Singleton();
    }
    return log;
}
public void imprimir(String msg) {
    System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    System.out.println(": " + msg);
}
}
```

Tengo esta clase que establece el usuario y lo valida donde se llama la instancia del singleton para imprimir la hora en la que entro el usuario o se desconecto

```
package Data;

public class Usuarios {

public String user;
public String password;
public String contraseñaMaestra = "hola";
public Usuarios() {
    user="";
    password="";
}
public String getUser() {
    String resultado;
    if(user.equals("")) {
        user="SinNombre";
    }
    resultado=user;
    return resultado;
}
public void setUser(String u) {
    user=u;
}
public void setPass(String pass) {
    password=pass;
}

public void validar() {
    if(password.equals(contraseñaMaestra)) {
        Singleton.getInstance().imprimir(getUser()+" logged");
    }
    else {
        Singleton.getInstance().imprimir(getUser()+" refused");
    }
}
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Data.Singleton.imprimir(String)" because the return value of "Data.Singleton.getInstance()" is null

este es el error que me sale, tambien tengo estos metodos para loguearse en otra clase:

```
package Data;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
public int o;
public String username, c;
Usuarios user_1;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
public Login() {
    
}

public void login() {
    System.out.print("Ingrese el usuario ");
    username=s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la contraseña ");
    c=s.nextLine();
    Usuarios user_1 = new Usuarios();
    user_1.setUser(username);
    user_1.setPass(c);
    user_1.validar();
}
public void logOut() {
    Singleton.getInstance().imprimir(": logOut");
}
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, se que el codigo no es tan efectivo sin embargo lo estoy haciendo sin ayuda como practica de programacion en java, me surgio esta duda por que no he utilizado singleton nunca

Answer (score 5, accepted):

es un error lógico, en la parte de código que dice

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if(log!=null) { // si log ya existe
        log = new Singleton(); // borralo y crealo de nuevo
    }
    return log; // si no regresa un nulo
}
```

La lógica está invertida

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if(null==log) { // si se da que log tiene el mismo valor que nulo
        log = new Singleton(); // creamos una instancia para el hilo actual (puede haber varias de hecho con esta implementación)
    }
    return log; // si no regresamos la que ya estaba creada
}
```